# sdk location doesn't found

Tags: 16.04, mount, android, sdk

I have installed android studio and I have located android sdk location to another disk part [E:] (Because of lack of free space). Every time if I don't open E: before opening android studio, android studio pop up "sdk location doesn't found". If I open E: before opening android studio that is OK. How can I make Ubuntu automatically mount E: disk part when i switch on my laptop.
If question is not clearly explained just write me I will try to explain again. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: find out where "E:" is mounted. To do so, open a terminal, and type `mount`. You should see something like this:

```
...
/dev/sdf1 on /media/username/something type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,block_validity,barrier,user_xattr,acl,uhelper=udisks2)
...
```

This shows you the device name of your disk (`/dev/sdf1` in my case), the mount point (in my case that's `/media/username/something`) and the file system type (`vfat` in the example).

Next, type `sudoedit /etc/fstab` in the terminal. This will open the `fstab` file in an editor. That file contains one line for every disk that should be automatically mounted. The line should look similar to this:

```
/dev/sdf1 /media/username/something vfat user,auto 0 0
```

You can see that you need to put the device name, mount point, file system type. After that follow some options. "user, auto 0 0" is probably a good choice.

You can try whether this works by using the commands `mount /media/username/something` and `umount /media/username/something`. If these commands work, your disk should automatically mount on the next reboot.